# Calculating $3^{m-n}=?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$9^m + 9^n = 52$$
$$9^m -4 = 2 \cdot 9^n$$

$$3^{m-n}=?$$

Let me show what I've tried

> Simpifyling the both equalities.

$$3^{2^m} + 3^{2n} = 2 \cdot 13 \tag{1}$$
$$3^{2m} -2^2 = 2 \cdot 3^{2n} \tag{2}$$

> Diving the second equality by $2$ and we have

$$\frac{3^{2m} -2^2}{2} =3^{2n} \tag{3}$$

Here is where I'm stuck.

My Kindest Regards!

Comment: Well, write your equations as $x+y=52,\;x-2y=4$.  Solve for $x,y$.

Comment: There are no solutions for integers $n,m\ge 1$. Usually $9^x+9^y=52$ is written for real $x,y$.

Comment: Normally problems like this are set up for $n,m$ integers, but that is not guaranteed.  Here the solution is not integral.  Did you copy it correctly?

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting
$$
x=9^{m}, \quad y=9^{n},
$$
we have

\begin{eqnarray*}
x+y&=&52\\
x-2y&=&4
\end{eqnarray*}
It follows that
$$
9^{m}=x=\frac{3x}{3}=\frac{108}{3}=36, \quad 9^{n}=y=\frac{3y}{3}=\frac{48}{3}=16,
$$
i.e.
$$
3^{m}=\sqrt{9^{m}}=\sqrt{36}=6,\quad 3^{n}=\sqrt{9^{n}}=\sqrt{16}=4.
$$
Hence
$$
3^{m-n}=\frac{3^{m}}{3^{n}}=\frac{6}{4}=\frac{3}{2}.
$$

**Remark:** The numbers $m$ and $n$ are obviously not integers, in fact 
$$
m=\log_3(6)=\frac{\ln(6)}{\ln(3)}\approx 1.63092975\ldots ,\quad n=\log_3(4)=\frac{\ln(4)}{\ln(3)}\approx 1.261859507\ldots
$$

Comment: The answer is given as $\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: @Fiv I don't understand your comment b/c the answer is given before the remark.

Comment: Oh I didn't see that lol! and I didn't understand it.

Comment: I'd suggest you Fiv , to learn some basic maths before coming on SE

Answer (score 4):

$$9^m + 9^n = 52$$
$$9^m -4 = 2 \cdot 9^n$$

By substituion, we have

$$(52-9^n)-4=2\cdot 9^n$$

$$48-9^n = 2 \cdot 9^n$$

$$9^n = 16$$

$$3^n=4$$

Substitute $9^n$ inside the first equation and do the same trick to complete the task.

Comment: I didn't get this step: $(52-9^n)-4=2\cdot 9^n$

Comment: from the first $9^m =52-9^n$, substitute that into the second equation.